# Flatten a one-to-one mapping in a multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data structure:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd

d = OrderedDict([
    ((5, 3, 1), {'y1': 1}),
    ((5, 3, 2), {'y2': 2}),
    ((5, 4, 1), {'y1': 10}),
    ((5, 4, 2), {'y2': 20}),

    ((6, 3, 1), {'y1': 100}),
    ((6, 3, 2), {'y2': 200}),
    ((6, 4, 1), {'y1': 1000}),
    ((6, 4, 2), {'y2': 2000}),
])

df = pd.DataFrame(
    d.values(),
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=['x3', 'x2', 'x1']),
)
```

The table looks like

```
            y1    y2
x3 x2 x1            
5  3  1      1   NaN
      2    NaN     2
   4  1     10   NaN
      2    NaN    20
6  3  1    100   NaN
      2    NaN   200
   4  1   1000   NaN
      2    NaN  2000
```

As you can see there is a one-to-one mapping between x1 and the columns (x1=1: y1, x1=2: y2) which I want to flatten into

```
         y1    y2
x3 x2            
5  3      1     2
   4     10    20
6  3    100   200
   4   1000  2000
```

How can I do it?

Edit: Or the other way round:

```
             y
x3 x2 x1            
5  3  1      1
      2      2
   4  1     10
      2     20
6  3  1    100
      2    200
   4  1   1000
      2   2000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for remove `NaN`, because create `Series`, remove `third` level by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
print (df.stack().reset_index(level=2,drop=True).unstack(2))
           y1      y2
x3 x2                
5  3      1.0     2.0
   4     10.0    20.0
6  3    100.0   200.0
   4   1000.0  2000.0
```

If need cast to `int` add [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
print (df.stack().reset_index(level=2,drop=True).unstack(2).astype(int))
         y1    y2
x3 x2            
5  3      1     2
   4     10    20
6  3    100   200
   4   1000  2000
```

EDIT:

```
print (df.stack().reset_index(level=3,drop=True).to_frame('y').astype(int))
             y
x3 x2 x1      
5  3  1      1
      2      2
   4  1     10
      2     20
6  3  1    100
      2    200
   4  1   1000
      2   2000
```

Comment: This fits my needs, thanks. May be you know also a way to do it the other way round (see my edit).

Comment: I found the answer myself: `df.stack().reset_index(level=3, drop=True).to_frame('y')`

Comment: super, also I add astype for convert to `int`

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 = df.unstack()
df2.columns = range(4)
df3 = df2.drop([1,2], axis=1)
df3.columns = ["Y1", "Y2"]
df3
```

gives

[image]